# RMI connection issue while using ehcache

Tags: java, rmi

Hi I have 2 web applications and I am using Apache Shiro and ehcache for enabling the SSO. My ehcache.xml file is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true" name="cache1">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/cache2" />

    <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
            properties="peerDiscovery=automatic,
                        multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.1,
                        multicastGroupPort=4446, timeToLive=1"
            propertySeparator="," />

    <cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory
            class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" />

    <cache name="shiro-activeSessionCache" maxElementsInMemory="600"
           eternal="true" overflowToDisk="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
        <cacheEventListenerFactory
                class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" />
    </cache>

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="true"
                  overflowToDisk="true" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

This configurations works fine if my rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0, but due to some reasons I have to configure it to my ip like below

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.131.210.201

In that case its throwing an error like below

```
**java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.131.210.201;**
```

Comment: This smells like a firewall issue.  Are the RMI applications running on the same machine?  In that case, it may well be that they were communicating over the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) before, and could do so again if you told them to do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 it is working fine 
but the problem is if i give the ip of my machine.

Comment: and yes all the applications are running on the same machine

Comment: As I said, this smells (even more strongly now) like a firewall issue.  If you communicate over the machine's external network interface then even if no packets actually go out over the network, the traffic must get through the firewall -- twice, once in each direction.  Firewalls are not typically configured by default to accept incoming RMI traffic.  But since it works on the loopback interface why not use that?  That's apparently what you were doing before (unbeknownst to you), and it's likely to be more efficient.

Comment: The problem is some of the tools i use needs the ip to be mentioned thats why i have to use that ip

Comment: Fine.  Go fix your firewall configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> This configurations works fine if my rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0

Impossible. More likely you didn't set it at all.

> but due to some reasons I have to configure it to my ip like below

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.131.210.201
```

You have to set it to the *most public* IP address of the server host. A 10.* address only works within the LAN it is part of.

Comment: rmi.server.hostname=0.0.0.0 yeah I am not setting it as what i mean is it works fine with that config. In my case all the applications are on my machine no external calls so what is the problem in setting the ip like that